# Get another permission in permission - Spring security

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I'm using `Spring security` for my project, and this is my configuration.

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.
                authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/home").hasRole("USER")
                    .antMatchers("/edit-information/**").hasRole("USER")
                    .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasAnyRole("ADMIN_STAFF","ADMIN_MANAGER")
                    .antMatchers("/admin/employee").hasRole("ADMIN_MANAGER")
                    .and()
                .formLogin()
                    .loginPage("/home/login")
                    .loginProcessingUrl("/j_spring_security_check")
                    .usernameParameter("email")
                    .passwordParameter("password")
                    .defaultSuccessUrl("/",true)
                    .failureUrl("/home/login-fail")
                    .and()
                .exceptionHandling()
                    .accessDeniedPage("/403");
    }
```

So it is my idea.
I want all ***ADMIN*** can log in to `/admin/**` but in `/admin/**` I have `/admin/employee`. I just want role ***ADMIN_MANAGER*** can log in here only.
But `.antMatchers("/admin/**").hasAnyRole("ADMIN_STAFF","ADMIN_MANAGER")` is already let ***ADMIN_STAFF*** log in to `/admin/employee`. I tried to add `.antMatchers("/admin/employee").hasRole("ADMIN_MANAGER")` but it did not work!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do believe the problem is in the ordering for that `antMatchers`. The order of the rules matters and the more specific should come first, so instead of this:

```java
.antMatchers("/admin/**").hasAnyRole("ADMIN_STAFF","ADMIN_MANAGER")
.antMatchers("/admin/employee").hasRole("ADMIN_MANAGER")
```

You can try this:

```java
.antMatchers("/admin/employee").hasRole("ADMIN_MANAGER")
.antMatchers("/admin/**").hasAnyRole("ADMIN_STAFF","ADMIN_MANAGER")
```